# In SQL Server, should I create synonym for a table or a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-performance, synonym

If this has been answered elsewhere, please post a link to it, yell at me, and close this question. I looked around and saw similar things, but didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I am currently writing several stored procedures that require data from another database. That database could be on another server or the same server, it just depends on the customer's network. I want to use a Synonym so that if the location of the table that I need data from changes, I can update the synonym once and not have to go back in to all of the stored procedures and update their references.

What I want to know is what the best approach is with a synonym. I read a post on SO before that said there was a performance hit when using a view or table (especially across a linked server). This may be due to SQL Server's ability to recognize indexes on tables when using synonyms. I can't find that post anymore or I would post a link to it. It was suggested that the best approach is to create a synonym for a stored procedure, and load the resulting data in to a memory or temp table.

I may not have my facts straight on that, though, and was hoping for some clarification. From what I can tell, creating and loading data in to memory tables generally accounts for a large percentage of the execution plan. Is using a stored procedure worth the extra effort of loading the data in to a table over just being able to run queries against a view or table? What is the most efficient way to get data from another database using a synonym?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use linked servers to do this however generally this sort of remote queries are not a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I have a choice but to use a linked server. My question is more about what the best way to get the data from the other database/server would be. Synonym for a stored proc that gets the data from the table/tables or a synonym for the tables themselves?

Comment: FYI: there's no such thing as a "memory table".  OK, well yes, there technically *is* in SQL Server 2012, but they are *very* specialized and not what people usually mean when they talk about "in-memory tables" in SQL Server.  *Usually* what they mean in a table variable, which for various reasons is widely believed to be an in-memory table.  It isn't.

Comment: Yeah, memory table is a term that I use incorrectly and I am somewhat aware of it, but I let it slip sometimes anymore. My understanding is that temp tables and table variables are all stored in TempDB. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonyms are just defined alias's to make redirection easier, they have no performance impact worth considering.  And yes, they are advised for redirection, they do make it a lot easier.

What a synonym *points to* on the other hand can have a significant performance impact (this has nothing to do with the synonym itself).

Using tables and views in other databases on the same server-instance has a small impact.  I've heard 10% quoted and I can fairly say that I have never observed it to be higher than that.  This impact is mostly from reductions in the optimizers efficiency, as far as I can tell.

Using objects on other server-instances, whether through linked server definitions, or OpenQuery is another story entirely.  These tend to be ***much*** slower, primarily because of the combined effects of MS DTC and the optimizer deciding to do almost no optimizations for the remote aspects of a query.  This tends to be bearable for small queries and small remote tables, but increasingly awful the bigger the query and/or remote table is.

Most practitioners eventually decide on one of two fixes for this problem, either 1) If it is a table, then just copy the remote table rows to a local #temp table first and then query on *that*, or, 2) if it is more complex, then write a stored procedure on the remote server and then execute it with INSERT INTO..EXECUTE AT, to retrieve the remote info.

---

As for how to use/organize your synonyms, my advice would be to create a separate owner-schema in your database (with an appropriate name like `[Remote]`) and then put all of your Synonyms there.  Then when you need to redirect, you can write a stored procedure that will automatically find all of the synonyms pointing to the old location and change them to the new location (this is how I do it).  Makes it a lot easier to deal with location/name changes.

Comment: Thanks! That was a great answer! The remote table that I need data from can get pretty large depending on the customer, so would you think option 1 is a practical solution?

Comment: @bsayegh  Try it and see.  It's hard to predict so the best course is usually to try the simplest/easiest way first.

Comment: Using a smaller subset of data, it seems like the first option was a little faster. Im guessing with more data the difference would be more noticeable. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Option 1 or 2 depends on the nature of your query. If you can retrieve the data with a relatively simple Select with a good Where clause to restrict the number of rows then Option 1 is generally the best choice.  DO NOT JOIN local and remote tables. Pull the remote data to a local #temp table and join the local tables on that temp table in a separate query.

If the query is more complex with multiple joins and/or complex Where conditions then retrieving the data into a local #temp table via a Remote procedure call is generally the best choice.  Again, DO NOT JOIN local and remote procedures and minimize the number/size of the parameters to the remote procedure.

The balance point between "simple Select" and "complex Select" is a matter of knowing you data and testing.

HTH :)